# Go code is reporting incorrect underlying array for an updated slice?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I have the following code ([Go Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/lkq1RNP_z_O)) which defines a slice (internally this will create an array and have the slice's pointer set to the array location in memory) and then appends a new value to it...

```
s := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}

hdr := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s))
data := *(*[4]int)(unsafe.Pointer(hdr.Data))

fmt.Printf("slice:  %T\n\t%#v\n\tlen: %d\n\tcap: %d\n", s, s, len(s), cap(s))
fmt.Printf("hdr: %#v\n", hdr)   // &reflect.SliceHeader{Data:0x40e020, Len:4, Cap:4}
fmt.Printf("data: %#v\n", data) // [4]int{1, 2, 3, 4}

s = append(s, 5)

hdr = (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s))
data = *(*[4]int)(unsafe.Pointer(hdr.Data))

fmt.Printf("slice:  %T\n\t%#v\n\tlen: %d\n\tcap: %d\n", s, s, len(s), cap(s))
fmt.Printf("hdr: %#v\n", hdr)   // &reflect.SliceHeader{Data:0x45e020, Len:5, Cap:8}
fmt.Printf("data: %#v\n", data) // [4]int{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

The problem I have with this code is the last line which indicates that although appending a new value will cause the underlying array to be recreated (as it needs to be resized), the value reported by the `data` variable appears to show the *original* array content (e.g. it has a length of 4) and not the updated content.

This is even though the `SliceHeader` that we're pulling the `Data` field from is showing the length of the underlying array as having the expected *updated* length of 5?

What am I missing here. Why would this final line not print something like `[8]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0}`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because after the append you use the data pointer from the updated slice header, but you still convert the data pointer to `*[4]int`, a pointer to an array with length=4. What length other than 4 could it have?

Doing so is OK, but you will only be able to access the first 4 elements of the underlying bigger array. Instead use `[8]int`:

```
data2 := *(*[8]int)(unsafe.Pointer(hdr.Data))
fmt.Printf("data: %#v\n", data2) // [8]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1f8dhsbFRtc)):

```
data: [8]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0}
```

Comment: oh wow what an idiot I am! I totally missed that ‍♂️thank you for pointing that out to me!